# PHP generated ICS file not working properly

Tags: php, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have the following ics file being generated on the fly by a php function. I'm having several issues with the file. On desktop, uploading to google calendar or outlook the time is off by 4 hours. On IOS the file works great, on Android the calendar errors with "No Valid Items".

I do not know much about ics files, and am attempting to learn. Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

First thing I'd like to fix is the time issue, why is the file not telling desktop apps the correct time?

Second thing is the "No Valid Items" on android.

```html
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Site //NONSGML Events //EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
X-WR-CALNAME:Example Site
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/New_York
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20160901T125454
UID:50
DTEND;TZID=America/New_York:20160907T210000
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160907T120000Z
DTSTAMP:20160908T154347Z
LOCATION:1234 Avenue Orlando\, FL 32803
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:Orientation
ORGANIZER;MAILTO:example@example.org
URL;VALUE=URI:http://example.site/schedule
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20160907T000000
DESCRIPTION:Orientation
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I believe I've solved the issue with time. 
'DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160907T120000Z' needed to have the Z removed to properly work with the timezone I had set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to find an answer by comparing an ics file that worked, from another website with what I had. I used an iCalendar Validator http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ to find the errors and discovered that the Organizer also required a name:

```html
ORGANIZER;CN=Example Name:MAILTO:example@example.com
```